# how to start building cooliris in openGL and C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, cooliris

I have seen the post where somebody commented that cooliris
can be built using C++ and openGL. I have just started learning openGL.
I wanted to ask how to go about creating it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must [decompress](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=245776) your video from codec stream into frame by frame stream in your texture [format](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/opengl/texture_formats/nv_ogl_texture_formats.pdf). Then each frame [render to texture](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html#example) that in [framebuffer](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) or create quad and render it with next frame as texture. While rendering you can apply shader [effects](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/OpenGL/src/gpu_videoeffects/docs/UserGuide.pdf) for creating some funny [filters](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/OpenGL/src/fast_third_order/docs/Gems2_ch20_SDK.pdf). You can find some tricks [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/vidimaging_samples.html)

Good luck!